# Is there an android dumpsys like utility in iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Having done a lot of testing on rooted android phones, I'll be switching on to iOS for my customer's app. Is there a dumpsys like utility in iOS which gives information related to the connected Wifi network, cellular connectivity, routing tables, battery info, memory and CPU info, etc.

It would also help me automate some test cases like I did in android using adb and string searches obtained from dumpsys, getprop

Although, the iPhone project has not started, but I'm suspecting that the iPhones we'll get are going to be rooted or jail-broken as that app would require root privileges to gain access to routing tables.

I verify routing using netstat. Something similar to that would be helpful.

Kindly note, I'm completely new to iOS and have no knowledge about it

Answer (score 1):

libimobiledevice - it is a very useful tool to get some information like battery details, wifi mac address.
Finding wifi IP address is tricky - get wifi mac address using the above tool and then arp -na|grep macid and get the IP address - this works only if the system and phone are in the same network. 
About getting CPU and Memory from commands, I have still no clue.